# How to make tag pages look as /tags/%tagname%/ in the URL?

Tags: tags, site-url

`Example Tag`'s page, which involves all blog posts tagged with it, resides at `/example-tag/` which is problematic for me since a post titled `Example Post` has the URL extension `/example-title/`.

How can I make so `Example Tag`'s page will be `/tag/example-page`?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Permalinks page.

In the Tag Base field simply enter `tag` and Save.

:-)

Comment: actually I thought the default tag base *is* tag already anyway...

Comment: I tried that but they are still the same :(

Comment: Weird. hmmm, maybe check your rewrite rules in a plugin that shows them, eg. https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/